# Poswershell Invoke-RestMethod return PSObject with some data in an array but not all

Tags: rest, powershell-3.0

I am trying to use Compare-Object against two Objects returned via Invoke-restMethod.

Using the vendors swagger page and all elements are fully exposed. IE no arrays:

```
    {
  "type": "SP",
  "id": "12345tygvcxsaw23456y",
  "name": "Stormtrooper",
  "entityId": "sb01.stormtrooper.com/SAML2",
  "active": true,
  "contactInfo": {
    "company": "Empire",
    "firstName": "Darth",
    "lastName": "Vader",
    "email": "DVader@stormtrooper.com"
  },
  "loggingMode": "STANDARD",
  "virtualEntityIds": [],
  "licenseConnectionGroup": "",
  "credentials": {
    "certs": [
      {
        "primaryVerificationCert": true,
        "secondaryVerificationCert": false,
        "certView": {
          "id": "bnjki98765rfvb",
          "serialNumber": "12345678912345678123456789",
          "subjectDN": "CN=stormtrooper.com, O=\"Empire, Inc.\", L=Tatooine, ST=Utah, C=US, OID.2.5.4.17=23456, STREET=3301 N Thanksgiving Way Ste. 100
```

When i get the same return using the Invoke-RestMethod it seems that elements that are two-deep are placed in an array:

```
    {
  "type": "SP",
  "id": "12345tygvcxsaw23456y",
  "name": "Stormtrooper",
  "entityId": "sb01.stormtrooper.com/SAML2",
  "active": true,
  "contactInfo": {
    "company": "Empire",
    "firstName": "Darth",
    "lastName": "Vader",
    "email": "DVader@stormtrooper.com"
  },
  "loggingMode": "STANDARD",
  "virtualEntityIds": [],
  "licenseConnectionGroup": "",
  "credentials":  {
                    "certs":  [
                                  "@{primaryVerificationCert=True; secondaryVerificationCert=False; certView=; x509File=; encryptionCert=False}"
                              ],
                    "signingSettings":  {
                                            "signingKeyPairRef":  "@{id=98765edfghu8765rfgh; location=xxx}",
```

Is there a way to 'force' Invoke-restMethod to return a fully expanded response?